# Reset the content of Input Queue of Tensorflow after each epoch?

Tags: tensorflow

I like to feed a new set of instances for each epoch of my training. The only way to me is to resetting the queue for each epoch. However, afaik once we tag the queue to graph there is no way to edit its content. Do you know any  solution or any other idea ?

I use string_input_producer to queue file paths and then dynamically read them and decode them into a batch in TF graph.

Answer (score 0):

The [`tf.contrib.data`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/data) API was designed exactly to solve problems like this, and I recommend you use it instead of queues.

Comment: It is the answer though since the tensorflow queue API does not support resetting.